Javascript array can have key value pairs?
Recently I was learning javascript Regular Expression on w3schools . And I found this quite strange example where it returns an array with key value pairs. Can someone tell me how this is possible or did I miss something? Thank you!
const obj = /e/.exec("The best things in life are free!");
 console.log(obj);
// the result is [
  'e', index: 2, input: 'The best things in life are free!', groups: undefined
]

const obj = /e/.exec("The best things in life are free!");
 console.log(obj);

I tried use both obj[0] and obj.input and they both worked . so I am confused.

Arrays are objects. They can have any property names, however for some good reasons it is usually better to use them as arrays.

JavaScript arrays can indeed have extra properties (and back in the olden days it used to be pretty common that people would mix and match objects and arrays) but it's not really good form.

Thanks for your help. It turns out that this exec() method returns an array object with additional properties such as index and input.  I was just confused by the console.log result where it shows an array with key value pairs in it which is impossible to recreate in the actual file.
